# How to get empty list [] instead of null for json.Marshal of []byte?

Tags: go, slice

It easy to get an empty list when working with string by using `[]string{}`:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice1 := []string{} // non-nil but zero-length
    json1, _ := json.Marshal(slice1)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", json1) // []
}
```

The output of code above is `[]`, **BUT** when I work with `[]byte` even using `[]byte{}` returns `""`. How should I get an empty list like what I get in `[]string{}`?

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice2 := []byte{}
    json2, _ := json.Marshal(slice2)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", json2) // ""
}
```

Comment: @mkopriva so I should use `[]int` ? How can I have []NumericField that outputs an empty list []?

Comment: Regarding the exception with []byte I have to use an alternative. @mkopriva please put your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.19#Marshal):

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, **except that []byte
> encodes as a base64-encoded string**, and a nil slice encodes as the
> null JSON value.

The part in bold is why you get `""`. If you want `[]` from `[]byte{}`, you need a custom named `[]byte` type that implements the `json.Marshaler` interface.

Or, if you're looking for a "slice of integers", then use `[]N` where `N` can be any of the basic integer types just not the `uint8` type. The `uint8` type will not work because `byte` is an alias of `uint8` so `[]uint8` is identical to `[]byte` and `json.Marshal` will output `""` for that as well.